# Where to find the introduction on how to use Canvas.configure()?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I saw some sample codes:

```
from tkinter import HIDDEN, NORMAL, Tk, Canvas

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
c.configure(bg='dark blue', highlightthickness=0)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Question:
Where to find the usage of `Canvas.configure`? I looked through [Python's Online Documentation](https://docs.python.org/), but did not find it. I googled it online and did not find it either. I only found `.itemconfigure`. It would be even better if you can tell me how to check all the methods of `Canvas`.

Comment: There's some documentation [here](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html). The `Canvas` widget's options are described [here](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas.html).

Comment: effbot documentation: [Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20190909161413/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.html). Original version was removed but this is backup on `archive.org`